# How can I create a scrollable mobile list view using dojo?

Tags: javascript, list, dojo

I want to create a list using dojo for a mobile application, which must also be scrollable. How can this be done?

Comment: I think a list will be automatically scrollable if the content is too long to display in a one-page view. Otherwise there must be a property to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view is a dojox/mobile/ScrollableView, then any lists in it will be scrollable. For example:

```
<div id="bookmarks" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView">
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading">Some Heading</h1>
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRectList">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem">Some item</li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem">Another item</li>
        <-- etc... -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile/ScrollableView.html

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah. I can do it now.